# Package mariadb-server-5.5 is not configured yet

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am having issues trying to upgrade my mariadb.....

when i do `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` i get the following error

```
Setting up mariadb-server-5.5 (5.5.47+maria-1~trusty) ...
 * Stopping MariaDB database server mysqld                               [ OK ]
 * Starting MariaDB database server mysqld                               [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-server:
 mariadb-server depends on mariadb-server-5.5 (= 5.5.47+maria-1~trusty); however                                                                                        :
  Package mariadb-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup erro                                                                                        r from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server-5.5
 mariadb-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on ServerFault

Comment: Alright sorry for the miss up

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be the result of a muddled setup between installing `mariadb` and `mysql`. Rebooting the machine and running `apt-get` again solved the issue for me.

Comment: thank you, mine did not work so i had bring down the server